# Convert modelstate validation strings to array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mbunit

Still not comfortable with all the enumerables out there. I'm trying to do this:

```
 Assert.IsTrue(actionResult.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid, null, Enumerable.ToArray<object>(actionResult.ViewData.ModelState as IEnumerable<object>));
```

It's an mbUnit assert with the following signature.

```
public static void IsTrue(bool actualValue, string messageFormat, params object[] messageArgs);
```

The third parameters causes (translated to english)

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Coin.UnitTests.AccountControllerTests.MyTest() in D:...\Tests\MbUnitTests\ControllerTests.cs:row 85

in Gallio. How do you do it?

Btw, does anybody know how to get these messages in English? Vista is in Swedish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModelState` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` so the cast ends up being null and `Enumerable.ToArray()` doesn't like nulls, hence the exception.

Try something like this:

```
var errors = actionResult.ViewData.ModelState.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray();
Assert.IsTrue(actionResult.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid, string.Join("\n", errors));
```

Comment: Well sort of. After a bit of fiddleing I turned up this (which compiles, could be different version MCV?):
            var errors = actionResult.ViewData.ModelState.Values.Select(e => e.Errors.First().ErrorMessage).ToArray();
            Assert.IsTrue(actionResult.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid, string.Join("\n", errors));

It works. Wonder if it could be made prettier?